# How to change/reset individual neurons during training

Tags: pytorch, custom-training

I would like to test what the impact is of randomly resetting certain neurons during training, in a Pytorch-based model with a number of linear layers like this:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(D, M)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(M, M)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(M, M)
        self.linear4 = nn.Linear(M, K)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.linear2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.linear3(x))
        x = self.linear4(x)
        x = F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
               
        return x
```

Ideally, I would like to implement a function/code snippet that resets the weights of 1 or more random neurons in each layer at the start of each epoch.

I tried implementing this via calls to parameters or state_dict, but so far I only get permission and anomaly errors when trying this. I'm also not sure whether this should be implemented in the module itself or in the training part.

Any suggestions would be highly welcome!

Comment: You're better off asking this question at the pytorch forums, a few of the Mods there are very helpful answering this sort of thing. With regards to your question, you need to dig into the actual source code of PyTorch, understand how the `nn.Linear` is implemented, and then find a way to achieve that. Also it's unclear what you mean by `resetting`. AFAIK, there are mechanisms (L2, Dropout) etc, which should provide a lot of useful info on how to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you, will post the question on the pytorch forum. With resetting I mean re-initializing. The idea is that each neuron has a small probability of being re-initialized each epoch, to see what the effects are on performance in general, as well as on issues such as dying relu's and vanishing gradients for sigm and tanh.

Comment: See: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-manually-set-the-weights-in-a-two-layer-linear-model/45902/2
And: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-change-the-weights-of-a-pytorch-model/41279
You may have to wrap around the layer class, subclass it, and keep index of what each one is/was. I suspect an indexing matrix may be of help here.